# Installed perfectly but password not working for login or authentication

Tags: software-installation, password, authentication

I installed Ubuntu on an old XP machine (replaced XP with Ubuntu) and it seemed like it went well... Until I tried to download and install the suggested updates!

The password I set during installation will not work for authentication. It won't even work for the User account. I thought maybe I'd typed the password wrong (twice) and checked online how to change it. Holding shift during start up won't give me boot options or grub so I can't get into recovery mode!

I've reinstalled three times (twice with the CD, once with the usb) and it's the same deal.

Basically, I'm sure I typed the password correctly, so I severely doubt that changing the password will help. It will automatically log in if I set it to do so during installation. Otherwise, I can only use the guest account and obviously can't setup another account or update software.

This is my first experience with Ubuntu and until it asked for the password, I thought it had gone so well. I sincerely hope I've missed something simple and I can get this working properly.

I'm surprised that I haven't found any questions with exactly the same issue. Please help! :)

#### Requested information

**1:** `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       147G  4.7G  135G   4% /
udev           1000M  4.0K 1000M   1% /dev
tmpfs           403M  836K  402M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1007M  176K 1007M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdc1       7.5G  4.7G  2.8G  63% /media/PENDRIVE
patricia@[computer name removed by me just in case it shouldn't be shared]
```

**2:** `dpkg -l | egrep 'lightdm|gdm|kdm|lxdm'`

```
ii  liblightdm-gobject-1-0       1.2.1-0ubuntu1          LightDM GObject client library
ii  lightdm                      1.2.1-0ubuntu1          Display Manager
```

**3:** Regarding whether or not there were error messages when logging in to a virtual console and attempting to change the password with `passwd` and `sudo passwd $USER`:

- No, I had to do the mount remount thing first but it said the password was successfully changed after that. It also tells me that I've successfully logged in...

#### New development:

I can now login to the user account created during setup.... I still can't use that password to authenticate though!

Hopefully we're getting closer.. Thanks so much for all your help :)

Comment: How is this still a thing?! *rage*

Answer (score 8):

## Summary: How This Problem Has Developed

So far, this problem appears to have progressed through two stages.

1. First, it was not possible to log in at all, on the graphical login screen. It was possible to log in on a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). Information obtained in a virtual console indicated that:

   - The output of `df -h` shows there's plenty of free space available. Graphical login has been known to fail when there is zero or very little free space on the hard disk, but that is apparently not what's wrong here.
   - The output of `dpkg -l | egrep 'lightdm|gdm|kdm|lxdm'` shows that the only display manager (which provides the login screen) installed is LightDM. This information was valuable because **a potential solution to being unable to log in** could have been to try a different display manager (for example, by installing and switching to `gdm`).
   - When changing the password, you said "had to do the mount remount thing first but it said the password was successfully changed after that." That suggests to me that you actually changed the password by booting into recovery mode, and *not* on the virtual console. If I am mistaken about this assumption, please let me know.
2. Now, you can log in, presumably by entering your username and password at the *graphical login screen*. (Please make sure to let me know if this is not correct.) However, you cannot authenticate *after* logging in. Therefore:

   - Changing the password appears to have fixed part of the problem. I'm guessing the password either had not been set properly during installation (perhaps due to some bug), or it contained characters that for some reason LightDM is unable to handle on its login screen, or it contained characters that mapped to different keys on your keyboard during installation than they did on the LightDM login screen. With your new password, you can log in.
   - *However, the problem is not entirely fixed, because you cannot authenticate after logging in.* I have preserved the general information I presented as my original answer in the first section below, entitled **Password Doesn't Work On Login Screen**. That information may be useful to other people who experience similar problems. *Please skip down* to the section called **Can Log In, But Other Authentication Fails**.

## Password Doesn't Work On Login Screen

#### A few things to check:

1. Is <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on?

   - Similarly, if you're using the numeric keypad to enter some of the characters, is <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> on?
2. Does your password contain unusual characters? (Perhaps you've found a weird bug.) Have you tried *different* passwords?
3. Did you set your password with a different keyboard layout from the one you're using to authenticate with it? If so, you may be typing in a totally different password.
4. Is your password blank (i.e., the zero character long password)? This doesn't work properly; you need to have an actual password.
5. Maybe something is systematically going wrong during the installation process. If you started with an Ubuntu ISO image, then:

   - If you mounted the image in Windows and installed from it without burning a CD/DVD or writing a USB flash drive, [MD5 test the ISO image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).
   - If you wrote the image to a USB flash drive or burned it to a CD/DVD, then in addition to the image possibly being corrupt, the installation medium (CD/DVD or USB flash drive) could be a bad burn/write. So boot from it and check it by [pressing a key when you see the keyboard and person icons at the bottom of the screen, and selecting *Check disc for defects*](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html).

   It's common for a bad ISO or a bad burn/write to prevent installation from succeeding, but it is also possible to get a broken installation.

#### As for fixing this:

1. You have a Wubi system<sup>*****</sup>, so GRUB runs *after* the Windows boot loader. Select Ubuntu on the screen where Windows and Ubuntu are you two choices, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hold it down, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This way, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is being pressed as the Windows boot loader chain-loads GRUB.

   - <sup>*****</sup>*Edit:* Actually, it turns out (from information you've since provided) that you do not have a Wubi system. I'm not sure why holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't work for you. Since the above advice applies whenever any boot loader besides GRUB chain-loads into the Ubuntu system's GRUB boot loader, it may work (or have worked) for you still. Otherwise, the problem could be that you are not holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key early enough in the boot process, or that you are releasing it too soon.
2. It's possible that this is, somehow, a problem with the graphical login screen. So you might be able to log in successfully from a text-based virtual console. To attempt that, boot the Ubuntu system, then after the graphical login screen comes up (or, even when you're logged in graphically as guest), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Enter your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then put in your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (You won't see anything happening as you enter your password but that's normal.)

   If you can log in to a virtual console, try changing your password by running the command `passwd`. If that doesn't work or you still can't log in graphically, try changing it by running the command `sudo passwd $USER`.

## Can Log In, But Other Authentication Fails

*This section assumes that you now **are able** to log in as the user created during setup, using the **graphical login screen**. That is to say that you can use your Ubuntu system via graphical user interface, not just as guest, but also as the user created during setup. If I have misunderstood, **please let me know**.*

You're able to log in now, but once you're logged in, you can't authenticate. There are three main types of authentication that are performed *after* logging in:

1. *Authentication to perform administrative tasks.* You are asked for a password when you try to perform actions that cannot be accomplished by an ordinary, unprivileged user, like installing software or changing system files. For this, *you use the same password as you use to log in*. Such authentication will only succeed if you are an administrator on the system. **I am assuming this is the kind of authentication that is currently failing.** Please let me know if my assumption is incorrect.
2. *Authentication to unlock the screen.* You can manually lock the screen, or you can configure the screen saver to lock it. It may also be locked when resuming from sleep (suspend-to-RAM) or hibernation (suspend-to-disk). For this, *you also use the same password as you use to log in.*
3. *Authentication to unlock your keyring.* The keyring may be used to store passwords (for example, for Internet services) or other sensitive data. *Your keyring password is **not** necessarily the same as the password you use to log in.* Unlike your login password, my understanding is that the keyring password *can* be blank, without causing problems.

The **things to check** for problems authenticating while logged in (whether to perform administrative tasks, unlock the screen, or unlock the keyring) are largely the same as for being unable to log in: Points 1-4 under **Password Doesn't Work On Login Screen** apply (except that point 4 doesn't apply to keyring passwords).

But I'm guessing you've already considered that. So, let's focus on problems specific to logging in to perform administrative tasks. These are the **things to check**. (Please note that this is long because it provides some instructions for *fixing* the problem, under some circumstances. Actually checking these things, generally speaking, is not particularly difficult or time-consuming.)

### Are you actually an administrator?

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
groups
```

That lists the [groups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26179/what-do-the-groups-do-in-users-and-groups) your user account is a member of. To be an administrator, `admin` or `sudo` (or both) must be listed. Please note that `adm` is a *different* group from `admin` and doesn't make you an administrator (though you should also be a member of that group).

If you're not an administrator, you can make yourself one by following any procedure for [resetting a lost password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password) (typically you'd [use recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/22949) for this, but [single user mode via editing GRUB boot options](https://askubuntu.com/a/132983/22949), or [`chroot`ing from a live CD/DVD/USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023), will also work). **Except** instead of running the `passwd username` command, run these commands:

```
usermod -a -G admin username
usermod -a -G sudo username
```

It's fine if one (but not both) of those commands fails. (If it fails, you get an error message. If it succeeds, there's generally no output.) What that does is to put you into whichever of the `admin` or `sudo` groups exist (or both, if they both exist).

### Are only *some* ways of authenticating to perform administrative tasks broken?

Ubuntu actually provides two underlying mechanisms for administrators to authenticate to perform administrative tasks--[`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) (which has graphical frontends such as [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html)/[`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html) and [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html)), and [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html).

In a Terminal window, **run this command**, to test PolicyKit:

```
pkexec echo Success.
```

You should be prompted for your password (probably by a graphical dialog box, but possibly in the Terminal window). If authentication succeeds and the word `Success.` is echoed back to you (i.e., printed in the Terminal), then PolicyKit works for performing administrative tasks (though it's possible it's still not working, for specific tasks).

Now **run this command**:

```
sudo echo Success.
```

This tests `sudo` in the same way (though the authentication will definitely be in the Terminal window--you *won't* get a graphical dialog box asking for your password).

Now **run this command**, to see if `sudo` is working graphically (run this even if `sudo` didn't work above, in case the problem has to do with the way the Terminal accepts input):

```
gksu xclock
```

You'll be prompted for your password. If that succeeds, a simple clock application will run. (You can quit the clock application.) **If that fails, run this** to see if the problem is that `gksu` is not configured properly:

```
gksudo xclock
```

If this is a Kubuntu system, then you will probably not have the `gksu` and `gksudo` utilities, so test with the `kdesudo` utility instead:

```
kdesudo xclock
```

#### If `pkexec` works but `sudo` and also `gksu` and `gksudo` (or `kdesudo`) don't work:

Either `sudo`'s configuration is broken, or `sudo` itself is broken. The former is more common, and easier to fix--I'll cover that here. (You'd know if `sudo` itself is broken because you'd get an error about how it refuses to run due to incorrect ownership/permissions, or an error saying `command not found`.)

Run `pkexec visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`, `sudo`'s main configuration file. Near the end of the file, you should see something like this:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

- If you're running a version of Ubuntu earlier than 12.04, don't worry about the `%sudo` line.
- If you're running Ubuntu 12.04 and later and you *did not upgrade* from a version of Ubuntu earlier than 12.04, don't worry about the `%admin` line (it might not even be present at all).

The `%admin` and/or `%sudo` lines (see above two bullet points) should be *uncommented*--that is, should *not* start with a `#` character.

After `%admin` and/or `%sudo`, there should be a space, followed by `ALL=(ALL) ALL` or `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.

If things are not as described above, you can edit the file to fix them. Since you're using the `visudo` utility to edit the file, it will catch syntax errors when you try to save the file. You should **not** attempt to override and save a file that it says has syntax errors. (`sudo`, and its graphical frontends, will refuse to work if the `sudoers` file contains even a single syntax error.)

If everything appears to be in order in your `sudoers` file, try reinstalling `sudo`. Assuming you haven't customized your `sudoers` file, reinstall `sudo` by running this command:

```
pkexec apt-get update
pkexec apt-get --purge --reinstall install sudo
```

However, if you have customized your `sudoers` file (before this--I *don't* mean the editing described above) ***and*** it's important to you that you not lose the customizations, leave off the `--purge` flag:

```
pkexex apt-get update
pkexec apt-get --reinstall install sudo
```

#### If `pkexec`, `sudo`, and `gksudo` work, but `gksu` doesn't work:

Run the command `gksu-properties` (this does *not* need to be run as `root`, i.e., **don't** run it with `pkexec`, `sudo`, or `gksudo`). Make sure **Authentication mode** is set to **sudo** and not **su**.

*Source:* [Password not working in Graphical Applications (gksu)? Works with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48215/password-not-working-in-graphical-applications-gksu-works-with-sudo) (Has a screenshot.)

#### If `pkexec` and `sudo` work, but `gksu` and `gksudo` (or `kdesudo`) don't work:

Try reinstalling `gksu`/`gksudo` (they're provided by the same package):

```
pkexec apt-get update
pkexec apt-get --purge --reinstall install gksu
```

Or if this is Kubuntu and it's `kdesudo` that's not working:

```
pkexec apt-get update
pkexec apt-get --purge --reinstall install kdesudo
```

#### If `pkexec` **doesn't** work, but `sudo`, `gksu`, and `gksudo` **do** work:

Try reinstalling PolicyKit:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install policykit-1 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
```

#### If `pkexec` works, and `gksu` and `gksudo` (or `kdesudo`) work, but `sudo` doesn't work:

`pkexec` usually authenticates graphically, like `gksu`/`gksudo` (or `kdesudo` on Kubuntu). So if graphical authentication is working for both PolicyKit and `sudo`-based methods, and console authentication is failing, there may be a problem with the way passwords are being entered into the Terminal. I've heard of this happening, but I'm not familiar with any concrete cases where it was known to occur and was then fixed. (Except where it was due to the user making a mistake entering the password in the Terminal.)

If this is happening, then to provide further information:

1. See if `sudo` works in a virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). This can help figure out if it's the graphical terminal application causing the problem.
2. See if `pkexec` works in a virtual console. When run in a virtual console, `pkexec` will not create a graphical dialog box. This can help figure out if the problem is *also* specific to `sudo`-based methods.
3. See if `su $USER` works, in both a Terminal window and in a virtual console. This command does not enable you to perform administrative tasks. It just authenticates *as yourself*. But it asks for a password (non-graphically) while doing so. This can help figure out the extent of the problem entering passwords to authenticate non-graphically.

#### If:

- the situation is different from all the combinations listed above, **or**
- the situation is one of the combinations listed above, but there's a problem following the instructions, **or**
- the situation is one of the combinations listed above and you've followed the instructions without apparent problems, but the underlying problem (of being unable to authenticate) has not gone away...

**Then please edit your question to provide details, and also comment here** (with or without `@Eliah`--when you comment on my answer, I'm always notified) **to let me know.**

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I can sign in using the text based console and I've now managed to change the password from there and from grub shift etc method. Still can't sign in using the gui though?

Comment: also just tried with sudo passwd... didn't help

Comment: I don't know how all this works... If I type @Eliah I'm hoping it will alert you to my reply. :)

Comment: I've updated my question with the answers. Hopefully it's what you requested. Thanks

Comment: Most important bit and I must have deleted it before I pressed Add comment lol   @Eliah

Comment: @Nick I've expanded my answer to provide information about how to troubleshoot the new "phase" of the problem (where you can log in, but can't authenticate after that), and also to provide situation-based solutions for some possible cases. Please don't be intimidated by the length--the actual troubleshooting shouldn't be too complicated, but definitely please comment if you have any trouble. I've used this as an opportunity to try to provide the necessary information to fix your specific problem, while also creating what I hope may later be turned into a valuable general resource.

Comment: I had the same issue, the keyboard layout was not the same

Answer (score 2):

I can see why this is terrible. First I want to troubleshoot with you. Check the following things:

1. Is my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on?
2. Is my <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> on?
3. Could any of these things have been on during the installation, when you typed in the password.

If none of this doesn't work, you could try again to boot into Recovery Mode. Here is a [good explanation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html) on how to use this method to fix your problem.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I just replied to the guy below. I have booted in recovery mode successfully now and I've changed the password. I've even managed to sign in with that password successfully but only in the text based virtual console.. not the gui. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick You could do the command `sudo reboot`, to restart and see the log in screen. If that does not work, then try `startx`. Glad to help

Comment: Could it be a question of keyboard layouts? Try typing the password in a Text editor or some other graphical app and see if it is what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long you've had this OS running, but if it's a new install why not just  **Nuke and Pave ?**  Reinstall your OS and you can have whatever password you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your gui login screen, on the top right corner close to network symbol, there is a square symbol with your current keyboard layout. Please select the correct layout for your keyboard, and then type your password. Hope that will solve your problem. After login remember to delete all other keyboard layout except the correct one from Text entry settings by clicking the same keyboard layout symbol on the top right corner.

Comment: You don't have to select the correct layout for your keyboard though. You have to select the layout that was active while creating the password. So if the correct layout doesn't work, try the other layouts too.

Answer (score 0):

The "encrypt home folder" feature seems to be broken. Just don't check this option when installing and you should be fine.