# Ubuntu will not set Account Password

Tags: password, users, password-recovery

When I enter my credentials and enter a new password, Ubuntu gives me no errors however. When I log out to log back in, there is no prompt for entering a password on the log on screen. I am just able to enter without entering any passwords. I have tried setting the password in the Terminal both "sudo passwd" and regular "passwd",but still no log in password is needed on the login screen.

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176337/installed-perfectly-but-password-not-working-for-login-or-authentication).

Answer (score 1):

This a system setting. Go to Systems Settings -> Security & Privacy. Under this you can see a button saying "Password Settings". When you click on the button you can see all the user list and their respective details. Select your account and click on Automatic Login - OFF. This prompts an option to enter your password every time you logout.

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix but that is not the issue, I made sure that was off the moment I set up Ubuntu. For whatever reason, it will not apply the password to my admin account.