# password fail ms surface go 2 new ubuntu install

Tags: password, surface

Ive just installed ubuntu 23.10.1 on a ms surface go 2. everything seemed to work fine until restart where it will not take my password. It will also not boot directly from the usb now which ive come to find out is because im using a usb-a with a hub. Ive seen this password issue asked but found no solid answer. Has anyone found a way to deal with this or do i need to get a usb-c stick and try a new install again?

I have gone over the link below and nothing in it that I can do helps wit this problem. I do not have a plug in keyboard atm to try any key presses prior to start up.

It would be the gdm3 password I cant get past. I can not re install atm, Im waiting for the proper usb c stick to come hoping that will help, I can not get the system to automatically boot off of this usb a stick. Was hoping to find an other way around this in case that does not work.

Comment: Have gone over this yet? https://askubuntu.com/questions/176337/installed-perfectly-but-password-not-working-for-login-or-authentication?rq=1

Comment: Which screen are you talking about when you say "it will not take my password"? The BIOS? The cryptsetup? Or the gdm3 display manager? Have you tried reinstalling with the password set to 123456, then changing it once you are able to log in?

Comment: In zwets' linked answer, there is a link to forcibly resetting your password: https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/1004020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so once I got a plug in keyboard this wasnt so bad. First figure out which key your unit uses to bypass the start up in favour of the bios. With my unit it ended up being the f4 key. Once there select the recovery mode. Take the drop to route shell prompt option. Here it accepted the root pswd I had set in the install letting me delete the user pswd (using sudo passwd -d "user name") that the log in wasnt accepting.